# Laravel 5.8 Auth::guard($guard)->check() always return false

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.8

I have two separate logins using guards which customer & adminuser. I have checkRole middleware for adminuser login and it works perfectly. I used guest middleware (RedirectifAuthenticated) to customer login. When customer login check with `Auth::guard($guard)->check()` it always returns `false`. But `Auth::guard('customer')->attempt` returns `true`. I can't find a solution.

here is the login controller for customer

```html
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->middleware('guest:customer')->except('customerlogout');
    }

    //login the customer
    public function customerLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->get('email');
        $password = $request->get('password');
        
        
        //Getting user inputs and authenticate the customer
        $status = Auth::guard('customer')->attempt([
            'email' => $email, 
            'password' => $password ] 
            );

        //Check login  
        if ($status) {
            //if login pass,redirect to customer account page
            return redirect()->intended('/customer_account');
            
         }else{
             //if login fail,redirect back to home page
             return redirect()->back();
         }
    }
    
    //logout the customer
    public function customerlogout(Request $request)
    {   
        Auth::guard('customer')->logout();
        $request->session()->flush();
        return redirect('/index');   
    }
}
```

here is the guest middleware

```html
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {       
        if ($guard === "customer" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/customer_account');
        }
        if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/index');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Kerenel.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{

    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];


    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \RealRashid\SweetAlert\ToSweetAlert::class,

        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];


    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'roles' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you check the value of the $guard inside your guestMiddleware?

Comment: @SachinKumar yes. guard value correctly returns `customer`

Comment: Could you please show you Kernel.php file contents?

Comment: @SachinKumar I have edited my answer and add the Kernel.php content.

Comment: I edited your middleware. Try with this one.

Comment: @SachinKumar can you tell me the changes you did?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211457/discussion-between-sachin-kumar-and-hashan).

Comment: @SachinKumar Editing a question is for improving the question's clarity, not for suggestions or solutions. If you have an idea you don't believe answers the question, add a comment. (If it turns out to provide an answer, you can copy your comment to an answer and possibly explain it a bit more.)